# C# unsafe type -> char*[] , getting a pointer on char array

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, pinvoke, unsafe

Have:

```
[DllImport("OpenAL32.dll")]
static extern void alcOpenDevice(char*[] devicename);
```

Wanna send the name to this function like smth that:

```
char[] data = "Hello!".ToCharArray();
char*[] txt = &data;
```

But getting the errors:

- > cannot implicitly convert type `char[] *` to `char * []`

  (funny error, because C# compiler refuses to define `char[] *` in /unsafe mode also :) )
- > Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type
  >   (`char[]`)

PS
When does `char` become managed? It's a struct, isn't it?

```
public struct Char : IComparable, IConvertible, IComparable<char>, IEquatable<char>
```

Although compiler showed info about declaring the pointer to a managed type (`char[]`). I can only suggest that when the type is an array CLR may present it like a managed type, but it sounds very crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

alcOpenDevice does not take `char*[]` or `char**`, it takes `char*`, which you should specify as a `string`. It also returns a handle.

```
    [DllImport("OpenAL32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern IntPtr alcOpenDevice(string devicename);
```

Comment: Ahh, I got confuse for a while. "char*[]" ? is that even valid ?

Comment: char* is valid for C/C++; char* in C# is different stuff, it's not a pointer to char-array in C#, it's a pointer to a single char ( main different between C/C++ and C# definition of char* )

Comment: @Icarus3 Yes, since the compiler accepts it. It is an array of `char*`. Use it to pass many `char*` to a function, by automatically marshalling the managed array to a `char**`

Comment: @OlegOrlov That is not true. It can be a pointer to many chars. An int* can be a pointer to many ints. Just like C/C++. You can use `fixed(int* intPointer = intArray)`

Comment: And without the keyword 'fixed', could it? :)

Comment: Not in my case. fixed is must

Comment: @lcarus3 turn on /unsafe at first, at the second "why must it be?" you can use without fixed, it's just an instruction, which isn't strongly required.

Comment: @OlegOrlov in any event, a pointer to a char array is also a pointer to the first char in the array, so it's not such "different stuff" after all.  The main difference is the fact that C# `char[]` refers to a managed object, which is why you have to take the address of a specific element of the array (and "fix" it, as well).

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky `fixed (int* intPointer = intArray)` still returns a pointer to a single int; it's just a pointer to an int that we know to be the first element in an array of ints.

Comment: C# `char` is not the same as C or C++ `char` (nevermind pointers or arrays).

Comment: @phoog it's different by technique and possibilities. Can you return the whole string via char* explicitly in C# as in C/C++ and define like char *str = "my string"; and manipulate with it via single pointer you defined, can't you in C#?

Comment: @phoog as I remember char is a struct and is a referenced object in CLR, not managed with boxing to the type "object" like System.String , so if you have unmanaged single char, char[] is an array of char structs char*[] - is an array of the pointers to the char structs, no?

Comment: @OlegOrlov This is too much to fit into comments. But no, you've confused yourself. First, strings are a special case because in C# they're 2 bytes per char plus 16-24 bytes of of other data, while in C they're 1 byte per char plus 1 null char. They must always be converted. 'struct' means allocated on the stack and 'class' allocated to gc'd heap. Heap objects must be pinned so the heap doesn't move them. Besides these differences, things are just like in C. Array elements are always sequential in memory, and you take the pointer to the first element. Fix the array before doing this.

Comment: @OlegOrlov int[] is an array of ints stored in the heap (unless you stackalloc it). int* is a pointer to this array. if it's on the heap, fix the array as you take its pointer. char[] is an array of 2-byte chars, whose pointer you can also take (if you want to) and typically need to fix. In the code I posted, .NET will automatically do string conversions, which is convenient.

Comment: @OlegOrlov char*[] would probably be an array of char pointers, but arrays cannot have pointers as their elements, so you cannot actually have an array of char pointers.  The point I was making is that a pointer to an array is actually a pointer to the first element of that array, so, assuming `V` is a value type, a pointer to `V[]` has the type `V*`.

Comment: @phoog "but arrays cannot have pointers as their elements" - really? try to init void* type both in plain C and C++ and C# you will get the type of array which has in its content the pointers ( array of pointers )

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Yes, strings are special, but System.String != System.Char and also they are different how do its handle in CLR. One it's referenced type and allocated from stack another otherwise from heap etc... And what heap? Isn't a heap a data structures which based on stack frames which are lists ( or leafs ) of binary tree "heap" by the name

Comment: @OlegOrlov You are correct; I misread the specification.  The correct statement is "CLS-compliant arrays cannot have pointers as their elements", which is of course not relevant to this discussion.

Comment: @OlegOrlov To answer your question about `char[]` being a managed type, no, it is not a struct, it is a reference type, as are all .NET arrays.  In other words, a .NET array of value types is not the same thing as a C or C++ array.

Comment: @phoog cool definition of the meaning "array". Isn't an array a data structure where each element goes near in memory like (for e.g. I shall use INT type of array): 0x0 -> 4; 0x04 -> 2; 0x08 -> 3 etc... As I remember it's the real definition of the array. Where we getting the size of type (int is 4 byte) and each element will be near to pervioes one and the region between them is only 4 bytes in int-array. In char-array - 1 byte etc.. So where is it different???

Comment: @OlegOrlov Your definition of array is the general case.  In the common type system, System.Array is a class that encapsulates that logic.  The type is a reference type; instances of this type have the data structure you describe, plus the usual CTS object overhead, plus some additional overhead that describes the rank of the array and the length of each dimension.  All array types, including `char[]`, inherit from System.Array and therefore have this overhead, and are heap-allocated, GC-managed objects.  That's why you need to "fix" the array when you assign its address to a pointer.